# DCP constraint version of $a^2 + b^2 \leq c^2$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, quadratics, second-order-cone-programming

I have a second-order cone constraint

$$a^2 + b^2 \leq c^2$$

where

$$ c_{\min} \leq c \leq c_{\max} $$

$$ a^2 \tan(z_{\min}) \leq b \leq a^2 \tan(z_{\max})$$

While $z_{\min} \leq 0$, $c_{\min}, c_{\max}, z_{\max} \geq 0$. This is a relaxation of an equality constraint $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. How can I express the constraint in a form fitting disciplined convex programming (DCP) [inequality requirements](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/tutorial/dcp/index.html#dcp-problems)?

This is very much a "learning" question for me, as I'm still in the process of learning about convex optimization, DCP, and SOCP. Additional details are appreciated!

Comment: Constraint in what variables?

Comment: @Masacroso: I would think this question about convex-optimization is very well suited for MathStackExchange.

Comment: @Masacroso it is certainly not a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Is $c$ known to be nonnegative? If not this isn't convex. If so, it's equivalent to $\|[a~b]\|_2 \leq c$.

Comment: Ah ha! Yes, $\ c $ is known to be non-negative. I forgot to mention additional constraints on a, b, c (updating jn the question).  $\ norm(a+b,2) <= c $ makes a lot of sense! I thought it would be simple just not *that* simple :) Thank you

Comment: @MichaelGrant if you want to post that as an answer I will mark it happily

Comment: Note that it is _not_ $\mathop{\textrm{norm}}(a+b,2)$. You have to stack $a$ and $b$ into a vector, not add them

Comment: Oh yes of course - that's what I meant to write (I was thinking $\ ai + bj $).

Comment: The link is broken